# How to disable public access to the source code in Google Code?

Tags: google-code

I have a private project, and i want it hosted on google code. this project is just for project members. How to enable browsing and submitting SVN code only for project members? I don't want other people to be able to do this.

How to disable public access to the source code in Google Code?

Comment: Star the feature request: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26676580/632951

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are no read restrictions on Google Code, so there's no way to create a project that's completely private.

If you want a private code repository, I recommend you check this question:

- [Free version control server provider for non-public projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430742/)

Answer (score 14):

You can't...

> We only intend to host projects that
>   are open source software projects,
>   documentation projects directly
>   related to open source software
>   development, and projects for the
>   development and maintenance of open
>   standards.

http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/MakingHostingBetter

Answer (score 3):

I think you can't.
Projects hosted at googleCode must be public!

Check [FAQ](http://code.google.com/support/bin/topic.py?topic=10380)

Answer (score 2):

You can't, but you can hide some tabs

Answer (score 1):

There are of course alternatives to Google Code. [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org) has free hosting and allows private repositories for free. There are some limits, but for a reasonably small project with few team members you might be OK.

Answer (score 1):

It's **currently** not possible.

However, there are currently [1663 stars on this feature request](https://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?id=1829). Since this is a feature that you want, you should **go along and star it too**.

The more stars the feature request gets, the higher the priority it gets. (Well, at least that's to be expected.)